# Gradle does not generate an output app Bundle with azure pipeline using Ionic cli

Tags: android, macos, ionic-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to create an app bundel (.aab) file using azure build pipeline.

I am running a `cmd` using mac os in build pipeline[image]

```
cd /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/platforms/android/

./gradlew bundleRelease
```

and I am getting this log

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_b8dje5mmhmfztq54lrcf1jtlp.run(/Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:153)
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:extractReleaseAnnotations
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12s
24 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 18 up-to-date
```

However, my build/outputs folder is empty. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you able to create an app bundel (.aab) file locally using the command line? Have you solved the deprecated warnings in the log? You may try to use Bash instead of cmd task (Run a command line script using **Bash** on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows).

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I also tried using Bash insted of cmd but still result is same.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes, I am able to create it locally.


the way I wrote cmd for build app bundle which you can see in image...is it correct?

Comment: Do you use the same cmd to create bundle? Could you set system.debug to True in your pipeline and share the entire log?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT  Yes... I run `ionic cordova run android` after that I go to platfrom/android folder and run `./gradlew bundleRelease`.  I get app bundle folder in `platforms\android\app\build\outputs` this location.  


I will share logs from pipline soon

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT  here is the link for log you asked for. 

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/epkrz7e9fjzhb4l/AAAv1hic9cDGIlEz6W2X-oVia?dl=0

Comment: How about using Gradle task directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops?

Comment: Tried with gradle task as well...same result. 
please see the logs: 
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll2rs4v3r70yqdi/Gradle%20task%20log.txt?dl=0

Comment: task :  https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zi2ppboikgz4pm/gradleTask.PNG?dl=0

Comment: It seems the Daemon is not compatible and a new one started, but there is some issue using the new one. Please try to use one of the Runtime version that build agent supports on your local machine, and check whether you can create an app bundel successfully. Also, you may try to solve the deprecated warnings in the log. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:why_is_there_more_than_one_daemon_process_on_my_machine